# how you use .query with pandas and numpy?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

From the file output_hc_v1.csv
with headers :emplid    pay_status  count   location    deptid  grade_desc date version

I would like via python save a new csv filtered on "pay_status=Active".
with this code:

```
a1=a.query ('"pay_status" == ["Active"]')
```

=========================================

but this part is not working.

```
My full code:
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv ("C:/Users/e1087353/Documents/CAPCO/HC/python_data/output_hc_v1.csv")
df.head()
a= pd.pivot_table(df, index =["location","deptid","grade_desc","pay_status"] ,values=["Count"],aggfunc=np.sum)
a1=a.query ('"pay_status" == ["Active"]')
a1.to_csv ("C:/Users/e1087353/Documents/CAPCO/HC/python_data/Output_final2.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to quote column names in the query string. Therefore you could use,

```
a1 = a.query('pay_status == "Active"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use query. To filter simply do:

```
a1=a[a['pay_status']=='Active']
```

If you create a pivot table you may want to reset the index before you filter:
    `a=a.reset_index()`

Alternatively, for more complicated queries, if you want to filter for items in a list use `isin`:

```
filter_list=['Active','Inactive','Something']
a1=a[a['pay_status'].isin(filter_list)]
```